# NetSuite Saved Search to Compare YOY sales to the end of last month

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

Trying to create a saved search that will display last years sales to the end of last month, and this years sales to the end of last month in two separate colmns using forumals.

I'm able to pull the sales for ALL of last year and ALL of this year using the formulas below:

```
-- 2021 Sales -- 
  (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR({TODAY},'YYYY')-1=TO_CHAR({shipdate},'YYYY') 
    AND {type} = 'Invoice' THEN {AMOUNT} 
    ELSE 0 END)+
  (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR({TODAY},'YYYY')-1=TO_CHAR({shipdate},'YYYY') 
    AND {type} = 'Sales Order' THEN {AMOUNT} 
    ELSE 0 END)+
  (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR({TODAY},'YYYY')-1=TO_CHAR({trandate},'YYYY') 
    AND {type} = 'Return Authorization' THEN {AMOUNT} 
    ELSE 0 END)+
  (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR({TODAY},'YYYY')-1=TO_CHAR({trandate},'YYYY') 
    AND {type} = 'Credit Memo' THEN {AMOUNT} 
    ELSE 0 END)

    -- 2022 Sales -- 
  (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR({TODAY},'YYYY')=TO_CHAR({shipdate},'YYYY') 
    AND {type} = 'Invoice' THEN {AMOUNT} 
    ELSE 0 END)+
  (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR({TODAY},'YYYY')=TO_CHAR({shipdate},'YYYY') 
    AND {type} = 'Sales Order' THEN {AMOUNT} 
    ELSE 0 END)+
  (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR({TODAY},'YYYY')=TO_CHAR({trandate},'YYYY') 
    AND {type} = 'Return Authorization' THEN {AMOUNT} 
    ELSE 0 END)+
  (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR({TODAY},'YYYY')=TO_CHAR({trandate},'YYYY') 
    AND {type} = 'Credit Memo' THEN {AMOUNT} 
    ELSE 0 END)
```

I tried to re-structure it to only show sales for both years through the end of last month (or last month for the previous year) but I keep getting an invalid expression:

```
(CASE WHEN {type} = 'Invoice' 
        THEN (CASE WHEN {shipdate}
        BETWEEN TO_DATE({TODAY},'YYYY')=TO_CHAR({shipdate},'YYYY') 
        AND TO_CHAR({TODAY},'MM')-1=TO_CHAR({shipdate},'MM')
        THEN {AMOUNT} 
        ELSE 0 END)
    ELSE 0 END)+
    (CASE WHEN {type} = 'Sales Order' 
        THEN (CASE WHEN {shipdate}
        BETWEEN TO_DATE({TODAY},'YYYY')=TO_DATE({shipdate},'YYYY') 
        AND TO_DATE({TODAY},'MM')-1=TO_DATE({shipdate},'MM')
        THEN {AMOUNT} 
        ELSE 0 END)
    ELSE 0 END)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `BETWEEN` condition, all expressions must evaluate to numeric, character or datetime values - in this case datetime.  Where you have

```
BETWEEN TO_DATE({TODAY},'YYYY')=TO_CHAR({shipdate},'YYYY') 
    AND TO_CHAR({TODAY},'MM')-1=TO_CHAR({shipdate},'MM')
```

the results of `TO_DATE({TODAY},'YYYY')=TO_CHAR({shipdate},'YYYY')` for example will evaluate to a boolean.  So it's like you're saying "If this date is between true and false" which makes no sense.  Try this instead for this year:

```
CASE WHEN {type} = 'Invoice' THEN (
  CASE WHEN {shipdate} BETWEEN LAST_DAY(
    ADD_MONTHS(
      sysdate, 
      TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MM')*-1
    )
  ) + 1 
  AND LAST_DAY(
    ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1)
  ) THEN {amount} ELSE 0 END
) END
```

And for last year:

```
CASE WHEN {type} = 'Invoice' THEN (
  CASE WHEN {shipdate} BETWEEN LAST_DAY(
    ADD_MONTHS(
      sysdate, 
      (
        TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MM')+ 12
      )*-1
    )
  ) + 1 
  AND LAST_DAY(
    ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -13)
  ) THEN {amount} ELSE 0 END
) END
```